# Vector of pod typedefs

Tags: c++, vector

Assume this declaration:

```
#include <vector>
typedef int int2[2]; // pair of integers
typedef std::vector<int2> vi2; // vector of integer pairs
```

Now, this `vi2` is not really usable. You [cannot resize](https://godbolt.org/g/kAygVy) or add items to it.
Why is this not allowed?..
(Obviously to fix it `int2` would need to be wrapped in a struct or a pair, but this is irrelevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are not copyable or assignable, both of which are requirements for elements of vectors.